# MethodNotAllowedHttpException, redirect to 404

Tags: php, laravel, routes

This is the list of a group of controllers:

```
Route::group([
        'prefix'     => 'some-prefix',
    ], function () {
        Route::get('/', 'MyController@index')->name('some-prefix');
        Route::post('/get', 'MyController@getData')->name('some-prefix.get');
        Route::get('/getall/{type}', 'MyController@getAllData')->name('some-prefix.getall');
        Route::get('/create', 'MyController@create')->name('some-prefix.create');
        Route::post('/', 'MyController@store')->name('some-prefix.store');
        Route::get('/edit', 'MyController@edit')->name('some-prefix.edit');
        Route::get('/{id}/edit/', 'MyController@edit')->name('some-prefix.edit');
        Route::put('/{id}', 'MyController@update')->name('some-prefix.update');
        Route::get('/cambiarestado/{id}', 'MyController@cambiarestado')->name('some-prefix.cambiarestado');
    });
```

I want to redirect to a 404 error when I type the URL:

```
http://myapp.com/some-prefix/ANYTHING-that-doesnt-match
```

Here's when I got the next error:

```
(1/1) MethodNotAllowedHttpException
in RouteCollection.php (line 251)
at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('PUT'))
in RouteCollection.php (line 238)
at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('PUT'))
in RouteCollection.php (line 176)
```

I put a `failOrFind` inside my `store` and `edit` methods in my controller, so I can redict to 404 routes like:

```
http://myapp.com/some-prefix/9999/edit
```

where the value `9999`doesn't exist, but how can I do what I asked?

Comment: What's the code of MyController@update and MyController@edit? Since these accept a dynamic parameter, you should handle the 404 there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Go to `App\Exception` open up `handler.php` in `render()` method add:

```
 public function render($request, Exception $exception)
 {
    if($exception instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException){
      return abort('404');
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
 }
```

Comment: I was adding some new lines there too, let's see. I have there some code that should be changed...

Comment: @leo please edit your code `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` not `MethodNotAllowedHttpExceptionn`, notice two "n" in the end.

Comment: Hello I am using Laravel 8 and I am unable to use Exception Class. Got error:
`Method 'App\Exceptions\Handler::render()' is not compatible with method 'Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler::render()`

Comment: Oh. Got it, nevermind

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like this in your routes:

```
Route::get('/some-prefix/{any}', function () {
    return abort('404');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying something like that too without success. I would pick this one as the correct one because I prefer to touch the Routes code than the Handler, but the problem is that I have many groups of similar routes... (my fault for bad code design, I should used `resource` instead get, post, put, etc)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did (I pick the answer of @Leo_Kelmendi as the correct one, I just want to share my whole code with the one he put too, by the way it has 2 'n' the `MethodNotAllowedHttpExceptionn`):

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    /*
     * Redirect if token mismatch error
     * Usually because user stayed on the same screen too long and their session expired
     */
    if ($exception instanceof TokenMismatchException) {
        return redirect()->route('frontend.auth.login');
    }

    /*
     * All instances of GeneralException redirect back with a flash message to show a bootstrap alert-error
     */
    if ($exception instanceof GeneralException) {
        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withFlashDanger($exception->getMessage());
    }

    if($exception instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException){
        return abort('404');
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```