# laravel MethodNotAllowedHttpException redirect to 404

Tags: laravel, exception, handler

I use laravel 8 tried to edit my exceptions\handler.php

```php
public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof MethodNotAllowedHttpException) {
        abort(404);
    }
    
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

but his gives not 404 but 500 when checking routes where MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MethodNotAllowedHttpException, redirect to 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46836778/methodnotallowedhttpexception-redirect-to-404)

Comment: nope that code of lines redirect to 500 error something doesn't work

Comment: If you use `\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException` instead of `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` , that will be work.

Comment: the same problem :/ in chrome 500 error in firefox blank page..

Comment: I'am trying to find solution but no luck at the moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to supply your `routes/web.php` file with a Route fallback. Try adding the following to the bottom of your web routes:

```
Route::fallback( function () {
    abort( 404 );
} );
```

Comment: Yes, this one works great for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

on Laravel 8 override default handler render function on App\Exceptions\Handler.php

```
public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof MethodNotAllowedHttpException) {
        if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson() || $request->expectsJson()) {
            //405 for Method Not Allowed
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Bad Request'], 405);
        }
        else {
            return parent::render($request, $exception);
        }
    }
}
```

don't forget to add *use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException;*
to test in Postman set *key=>Accept ,value => application/json* to test handler
reff: [Return a 404 when wrong ttp request type used(e.g. get instead of post) in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59027326/return-a-404-when-wrong-ttp-request-type-usede-g-get-instead-of-post-in-larav)